# How to create a simple cpu benchmark?

Tags: c++, cpu, benchmarking, multicore

For a school project, which is highly relevant for our A-Levels, we want to overclock a Raspberry Pi's CPU and evaluate the performance of the CPU, prior to and post overclocking it, with a self-written benchmark.

This benchmark should be as simple as possible as it only repesents a smaller part of our presentation.

We thought it might be a good idea to use **c++** as the language since it uses less resources(?).
For the benchmark itself we thought about using somthing like an algorithm that calculates Pi or prime numbers to a specific point and see how long it takes.

How can we use multiple cores/a single core?

Are there a better/simpler alternatives to our thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's Pi (the number), not Pie (the baked pastry).

Comment: A benchmark can be as trivial as you want.  If you just want something that will scale linearly with clock speed, `for(uint64_t i = 0; i< MAX_COUNT ; i++) {}` is a simple micro-benchmark that only means anything in a relative sense, or if you look at the compiler generated asm.  (You have to avoid having it optimize away to nothing.  e.g. compile with `gcc -O1` or lower.  https://godbolt.org/g/aejRPt)

Comment: You can run multiple instances of a single-threaded executable, e.g. in bash `for i in {1..4};do ./benchmark & done` to start 4 background jobs.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry, fixed that

Comment: BTW, a benchmark that *doesn't* scale linearly with clock clock speed might be more interesting.  e.g. one that depends partly on memory bandwidth / latency.  The faster the CPU is, the more CPU clocks a cache miss takes.  A prime number sieve of Eratosthenes might be good, and easy to implement.  Or a Quick Sort or Merge Sort.  (Merge Sort parallelizes easily.)

Comment: @PeterCordes As simple as that? Thanks a lot, I thought it to be much harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A benchmark can be as trivial as you want. If you just want something that will scale linearly with clock speed, the following is a simple micro-benchmark:

```
for(uint64_t i = 0; i< MAX_COUNT ; i++) {}
```

It only means anything in a relative sense, or if you look at the compiler generated asm.

You have to avoid having it optimize away to nothing, e.g. compile with `gcc -O1` or lower.

[Example](http://godbolt.org/g/aejRPt)

You can run multiple instances of a single-threaded executable, e.g. in bash:

```
for i in {1..4};do ./benchmark & done
```

to start 4 background jobs.

– Answer by Peter Cordes.